# context.read<UserRepository>() called with a request context that does not contain a UserRepository

Tags: dart, authentication, http, dependency-injection, backend

## Problem

Whenever I try to acces `/auth` Endpoint, I get an `Internal Server Error` and get this Error, eventhough other endpoints work as intended:

````
ERROR - 2023-12-24 00:21:23.309836
POST /auth
Error thrown by handler.
Bad state: context.read<UserRepository>() called with a request context that does not contain a UserRepository.
 
This can happen if UserRepository was not provided to the request context:
  ```dart
  // _middleware.dart
  Handler middleware(Handler handler) {
    return handler.use(provider<T>((context) => UserRepository());
  }
  ```
 package:dart_frog/src/context.dart 29:7  RequestContext.read
 routes\auth\index.dart 25:24             _authUser
````

From the errormsg, the problem seems that `repo` doesn't have access to the Dependency, I've logged the rest of the code to try to understand why this is happening but it seems the only problem is from that line of code, here's all referenced code that's used by '/auth' Endpoint, please don't focus on JSON responses:

### routes/auth/index.dart

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dart_frog/dart_frog.dart';
import 'package:test_dart_frog_server/user_repository.dart';

Future<Response> onRequest(RequestContext context) async {
  return switch (context.request.method) {
    HttpMethod.post => _authUser(context),
    _ => Future.value(Response(body: 'This is default'))
  };
}

Future<Response> _authUser(RequestContext context) async {
  final json = (await context.request.json()) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  
  final username = json['username'] as String?;
  final password = json['password'] as String?;

  if (username == null || password == null) {
    return Response.json(
      body: {'message': 'Username or password not the same!'},
      statusCode: HttpStatus.badRequest,
    );
  }
  final repo = context.read<UserRepository>();
  final user = await repo.authUser(username: username, password: password);

  return Response.json(
    body: {'user': user},
  );
}
```

### lib/user_repository.dart //authUser() method

```dart
Future<User?> authUser(
      {required String username, required String password}) async {
    final user = await _db.user.findFirst(
      where: UserWhereInput(
        username: StringFilter(equals: username),
        password: StringFilter(equals: _hashPassword(password)),
      ),
    );
    return user;
  }
```

###### Note: I'm new to dart_frog and backend in general, also I can share a Github repo if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution!

`repo` can't access dependency because `_middleware` isn't global.
This can be solved either by making `_middleware` Global or by adding another `middleware` to `/auth` as I did:

1. Run this to create a new middleware for `/auth`.

```
dart_frog new middleware "/auth"
```

2. Provide the required Dependencies there.